# RichFaces h:selectOneMenu a4j:support not working when initialised with materialCSS multi_select()

Tags: material-design, richfaces, selectonemenu, ajax4jsf

**Disclaimer - I am newbie to richfaces as I used to work on .net platform earlier** :)

I am trying to change the theme of the `RichFaces` application with `materialize css`. I have a simple `h:selectOneMenu` as below

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{testBean.presetDate}" valueChangeListener="#{testBean.resetValues}" id="presetDate">
    <f:selectItem itemValue="-1" itemDisabled="true" itemLabel="Select days" />
    <f:selectItems value="#{testBean.listOfPresetDates}" />
    <a4j:support event="onchange" ajaxSingle="true">
    </a4j:support>
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

and my `resetValues` method inside `testBean.java` is as follows:

```
public void resetValues(ValueChangeEvent valueChangeEvent) {
    //some processing here
}
```

and I have been initialising this `selecOneMenu` with `materialize css` `multi_select()` plugin as below:

```
$('select').material_select();
```

But whatever I do, the `valueChangeListner` doesn't trigger at all. I mean, it never calls the method in server. I also tried putting that method as `actionListener` in `a4j:support` and changing parameter of server method as `ActionEvent`, but even that doesn't help. Anything else I have to configure along with this?

**Note:** Earlier design had `rich:combobox` instead of `selectOneMenu` which was working fine with `changeListener`, but the plugin will not be able to convert this to required `material select` since, the above will not render `select` element, rather it renders `table` and `inputs` in `DOM`.

---

**EDIT**

Forgot to mention one thing. We are loading this page through `ajax` request as below:

```
<a4j:form id="pageForm" rendered="#{prevBean.selectedPage == 'bth'}">
    <a4j:include viewId="/newPage.jsp" id="newPage" rendered="#{prevBean.selectedPage == 'bth'}" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
         jQuery(document).ready(function() {
             initSelect_DatePicker();
         });
    </script>
</a4j:form>
```

This `newPage.jsp` contains above control. Will this be a cause for the above problem?

Comment: Does the AJAX request happen or not? If not try removing the `material_select` and see if that helps. (btw. if you're just starting with RichFaces why are you using RichFaces 3?)

Comment: @Makhiel I think I had wrong perception, ajax request doesn't happen at all buddy and as per your suggestion I tried removing that even then it did not happen. Its already a built application and am trying to modify it.. Any suggestions?

Comment: No errors in the console? The include shouldn't prevent AJAX though it will prevent the listener from executing if the rendered condition becomes false.

Comment: Console errors exists only for not finding `Roboto font`. Other than that all good.. Sometimes I will get `modalPanel.js` file console error on certain scenarios. But am not able to replicate the exact scenario for that error.. Will that matter however? If so, as I said earlier `rich:combobox` works well with `a4j:support`.. @Makhiel